# ASP.net Kestrel some queries are very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net, kestrel

I'm working on a ASP.net (.net Core 2.0) application, and I realize that some queries are very slow.

It's an API, the entrypoint just do a query to mongoDB (Aggregate) and return the result.

When I run 10 requests one of them will be very slow, 10 seconds, while the others will be proceed in 200 ms.

At the beginig I suspected Mongo to be the problem but when I execute the exact same query in direct to the mongo database I don't reproduce the problem.

In application logs, the time deltas appeares just between this two lines :

`2018-09-20T09:07:02.253335192Z Connection id "0HLGUR04B579R" started.
2018-09-20T09:07:10.761709905Z info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]`

It's why I suspect Kestrel, but I don't really know what to do to improve perfomances and resolves this problem.

I have upgrade the .net core version to 2.1 but I'm still facing the same problem.

If someone has an idea...

Comment: Man, if the answer helps you, you might want to mark it as the answer so that it can help other guys with the same problems in the future.

Comment: What you need is a profiler. Take a profile, and it'll likely tell you what's happening

Answer (score 0):

To solve your problem, you have two options:

First:

Try to execute some warm-up queries after deploying your app.

Second:

If you have tons of RAM (memory in the cloud is now more affordable), you might wanna try to use the [touch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/touch/) command, which enables you to pre-load data from the disk to the memory.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your reply, I will have a look to this.
But If I understand well, this assume that MongoDB is the problem, but I'm not sure of this.
Indeed I have done several tests without use .net Framework but executing request directly on the mongo db, and I don't reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's more likely a feature of JIT (Just-in-time) compiler. This is the reason why I suggested the warm-up queries to force JIT to execute. Touch command is more of on the DB side.

Comment: Ok, but I often have this problem, not just after deployed the app. Kestrel is closing and opening connection when a request is coming and some times it  take a while before to execute the request.